# sequelize update column by id from object array

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a table:

```
id, url, storage
3, www.a.com, null
7, www.b.com, null
```

Now I fetch the html and save it in a location (storage).

My code produces an object with the ids and their corresponding storage locations:

```
{ 
    3: 'C:',
    7: 'D:'
}
```

How can I batch update the entries from this information so it will become

```
id, url, storage
3, www.a.com, C:
7, www.b.com, D:
```

I use sequelize to communicate with the DB

Answer (score 0):

`Model` is an instance of your model, that connects to you table. It would have 3 attributes: `id, url, storage`.

For example, this is how I assume you have set it up:

```
var Model = db.define('Model',
  {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    url: { type: Sequelize.TEXT },
    storage: { type: Sequelize.STRING(1) }
  },
  {
    tableName: 'my_table_name',
    timestamps: false
  });
```

Now you can use the `findAll()` method to retrieve all entries in your table, filter them based on your object, and set the `storage` property on the entries and save to DB:

```
var obj = {3: 'C:',7: 'D:'};

Model.findAll()
  .filter(function(entry) {
    // filter returns only those entries that have IDs present in the obj
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(entry.id);
  })
  .map(function (filteredEntry) {
    // Ex.:
    // filteredEntry = {"id": 3, "url": "www.a.com", "storage": null}
    // obj[filteredEntry.id] == obj[3] == 'C'
    filteredEntry.storage = obj[filteredEntry.id];
    return filteredEntry.save();
  })
  .then(function (entries) {
    //Do something else
  });
```